# Issue with rake db:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rbenv

I think this is a common problem, but I've tried what I've read in several other posts and I'm meeting the same fate.

I'm using rbenv because that is what I came across first.

```
rake db:create
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in `rescue in spec'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:174:in `spec'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `establish_connection'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:15:in `create'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:93:in `create'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:107:in `block in create_current'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:275:in `block in each_current_configuration'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each_current_configuration'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:106:in `create_current'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
    /Users/cmunger/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
    Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"blogApp", "password"=>"*****", "socket"=>"/tmp/mysql.sock", "database"=>"blog_test"}
    rake aborted!
    Gem::LoadError: Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).

Gem::LoadError: can't activate mysql2 (~> 0.3.13), already activated mysql2-0.4.2. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile
```

My version and bundle install.  mysql2 is there...

```
cmunger@Claytons-Mac:~/Desktop/Devlopment/blog$ rbenv versions
  system
* 2.2.3 (set by RBENV_VERSION environment variable)
cmunger@Claytons-Mac:~/Desktop/Devlopment/blog$ bundle install
Using actionmailer 4.2.4
Using actionpack 4.2.4
Using actionview 4.2.4
Using activejob 4.2.4
Using activemodel 4.2.4
Using activerecord 4.2.4
Using activesupport 4.2.4
Using arel 6.0.3
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using builder 3.2.2
Using bundler 1.10.6
Using byebug 8.2.1
Using coffee-rails 4.1.0
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.0
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using execjs 2.6.0
Using globalid 0.3.6
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using jbuilder 2.3.2
Using jquery-rails 4.0.5
Using json 1.8.3
Using loofah 2.0.3
Using mail 2.6.3
Using mime-types 2.99
Using mini_portile2 2.0.0
Using minitest 5.8.3
Using multi_json 1.11.2
Using mysql2 0.4.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.7
Using rack 1.6.4
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using rails 4.2.4
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
Using railties 4.2.4
Using rake 10.4.2
Using rdoc 4.2.0
Using sass 3.4.20
Using sass-rails 5.0.4
Using sdoc 0.4.1
Using spring 1.5.0
Using sprockets 3.5.2
Using sprockets-rails 2.3.3
Using thor 0.19.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tilt 2.0.1
Using turbolinks 2.5.3
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using uglifier 2.7.2
Using web-console 2.2.1
Bundle complete! 12 Gemfile dependencies, 54 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

I think the error below might be the root of my problem:

```
Gem::LoadError: can't activate mysql2 (~> 0.3.13), already activated mysql2-0.4.2. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile
```

I try to change it back, but I get:

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.4.2'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command mysql2,
```

Any further information I can provide please ask.  I followed a wiki on the install using rbenv and this is where I'm at.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you're running Rails 4.2.5 or higher, you'll want to put the following in your `Gemfile`:

`gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.10'`

Source: [mysql gem compatibility listing](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#compatibility)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `bundle exec` to you command, otherwise you execute it on a global gemset:

```
bin/rake db:create
```

As an alternative, you could use binstubs:

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```

Comment: You just need to add the gem `mysql2` to the `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`

Comment: @YuryLebedev, I think you have reversed the order of the code snippets in your answer

Comment: @benjamin you meen that binstubs is a preferred way? I also thought so, but wanted to keep the answer closer to the initial question

Comment: @YuryLebedev, it is in my gemfile, but still errors out with the above error.

Comment: @YuryLebedev, this is not what I have meant. Your answer reads like you mean "bundle exec..." were a binstub.

Comment: @YuryLebedev, mysql2 is in there http://pastebin.com/sumedqk2.  Still getting: Gem::LoadError: Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).

Gem::LoadError: can't activate mysql2 (~> 0.3.13), already activated mysql2-0.4.2. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.

Comment: I got it to work, by going into gem file and changing the mysql2 to gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'  then doing bundle install

Answer (score 2):

for Rails 4.2.5 or higher use this

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
```

then

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 1):

In your gemfile use only (for now)

```
gem mysql2
```

In your command line, run

```
$ gem install -v '0.3.13'
$ bundle exec bundle update
$ bundle exec bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a bit of extra advice to anyone who has tried all of the above and is still facing the same problem.

I initially tried

1. installing rbenv
2. setting `rbenv global` and `rbenv local` to the desired versions
3. creating a `.ruby-version` file in my project set to the desired version
   4, putting the suggested rbenv entry in my .bash_profile
4. tested my setup with `rbenv version` and got what I expected
5. and tried a bunch of other things suggested on this thread

and nothing worked.

In the end, after hours of banging my head and trying different things, what finally resolved the situation was rebooting.  So just a tip: if all else fails in all this advice, don't waste hours like me: just reboot.

I first encountered the issue when running `bundle install`.  The rbenv steps listed above combined with a reboot fixed the issue.  Then the problem came back on the `rails db:create` command even though `bundle install` was still working in the same bash session!  Once again I checked everything and what finally fixed it was rebooting.